# Orders of reductions of rational points on elliptic curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, abelian-varieties

I am looking for references where the following (or similar questions) have been studied:

Let $K$ be a number field or a function field in one variable over a finite field and let $E$ be an elliptic curve (or more generally, an abelian variety) over $K$. If $x \in E(K)$ is a point of infinite order then the order of its reduction modulo a good prime tends to infinity with the order of the residue field.

> Are there any results that are known about the prime factorisation of the order of the reduction of $x$? For example, is it known that there is an infinite sequence of rational primes $p_i$ and primes $P_i$ of (the ring of integers of) $K$ such that $p_i$ divides the order of the reduction of $x$ modulo $P_i$?

I would also be interested in similar statements for the order of the group of rational points on the reduction of any  elliptic curve $E$ modulo primes of $K$.

(I expect that much stronger results should be true, but don't know the literature in this area.)

Comment: Maybe the results on elliptic divisibility sequences could help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_divisibility_sequence.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault: They do indeed. More specifically, an application of Siegel's integrality finiteness theorem as in section 2 of Silverman's *Wieferich's criterion and the $abc$ conjecture* is enough to give infinitely many $p_i$ (ineffectively). Much more can be said, as I tried to indicate in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For example, is it known that there is an infinite sequence of rational primes $p_i$ and primes $P_i$ of (the ring of integers of) $K$ such that $p_i$ divides the order of the reduction of $x$ modulo $P_i$?

Yes, a weak and ineffective form of this at least follows from Siegel's integrality finiteness theorem. See the above comments for a reference.

A lot more can be said. Conditionally on the GRH for Dedekind zeta functions,  Miri and Murty proved  that $|E(\mathbb{F}_P)|$ has at most $16$ prime factors (counting multiplicities!) for $\gg_E X / (\log{X})^2$ of the primes $P$ of norm $N(P) \leq X$. This they did by adapting Chen's method for his almost twin primes theorem; note that the problem of getting infinitely many prime orders of $E(\mathbb{F}_P)$ could be regarded as an elliptic variant of the twin prime problem. See Theorem 5 with the original reference [25] in [this paper of Cojocaru](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~cojocaru/cojocaru-CNTA-2004.pdf), as well as [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00208-008-0249-9) of hers for an unconditional proof in the CM case that $|E(\mathbb{F}_P)|$ is essentially squarefree infinitely often (with the right density in fact).

Comment: Thanks a lot!  The Miri--Murty result is exactly the kind of statement that I was hoping would be true. (In dynamical terms, I expect that if $f:X \to X$ is a selfmap of a variety over a number/function field $K$ and $x \in X(K)$ is a point of infinite order, then there exists an integer $n>0$ and infinitely many primes $P_i$ of $K$ such that the reduction of $f^n(x)$ modulo $P_i$ is a periodic point.)

Comment: I've been looking at the proof of the Miri--Murty theorem and have some doubts. They claim (bottom of  p. 95) that there are many primes $p$ so that $|E(\mathbb{F}_p)|$ has only one "small" prime factor. However, $|E(\mathbb{Q})|$ could have more than one prime factor so I don't see how their claim could possibly be correct (unless they are assuming that $E(\mathbb{Q})$ is trivial, but this is not stated explicitly anywhere).

Comment: Sorry, $E(\mathbb{Q})$ should have been $E(\mathbb{Q})_{tors}$.

Comment: I don't have an access to their paper at the moment, but as $|E(\mathbb{Q})_{\mathrm{tors}}|$ is in any case uniformly bounded, surely such a condition can't make much of a difference? Could they intend e.g. only one small prime factor $q > 11$, or not dividing the order of the torsion subgroup?

Comment: I don't understand the details of their proof, but it is fairly short and they do not  seem to be making any assumptions on the primes nor do they refer to Mazur's theorem. In fact they claim that  there are only 16 prime factors with multiplicity: this also seems a bit off since if there is one "very small" prime factor then a large power of that prime could still divide the order. (I will look at the paper of Silverman that you referred to instead, since there is no dependence on GRH)

Comment: Yes, Silverman's Zsigomndy theorem is good enough for your sample statement (but ineffective). As for Miri-Murty, I'll try to look into their paper when I get a chance (I don't have it available right now), but it is indeed common in the 'elliptic twin prime' problem to be assuming that $E(\mathbb{Q})_{\mathrm{tors}} = \emptyset$ (else $|E(\mathbb{F}_p)|$ can certainly not be a prime), so my guess would be they may be working under this assumption. If so, their method surely extends to give similar results in general, including over an arbitrary global field.

Comment: (Sorry, I intended of course $E(\mathbb{Q})_{tors} = \{O\}$ (trivial), not $\emptyset$.)

Comment: I do want a stronger statement than what I had written: what I really need is that (for fixed $E$) given any integer $m > 0$, there exists an infinite set of primes $T_m$ so that the $m$-primary part of the order of $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is bounded above by a constant independent of $p \in T_m$.  This follows immediately from Miri--Murty, but is of course much weaker.

Comment: For your stronger statement it would be also enough to know that $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ has an essentially squarefree order (squarefree up to a bounded factor depending on $E$) for a positive density of the primes $p$. This appears to be 'known' to be possible in principle, for in her last paper I referenced to, where Cojocaru treats unconditionally the case of a CM elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ and ordinary primes, she comments: *The case of elliptic curves without CM is based on different ideas and is also relegated to a separate paper.*

Comment: On her web page ( http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~cojocaru/acc-research.html ), there is also listed a manuscript in progress about the function field case: A.C. Cojocaru, Á. Tóth and F. Voloch, *Squarefree orders for the reductions of an elliptic curves over a function field*. Perhaps it could be a good idea to address the question to one of these authors.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for the references!