# What's the average order of the reduction of a section of an elliptic curve

Tags: analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Suppose $E$ is an elliptic curve over $\mathbb Q$ and $x \in E(\mathbb Q)$ is not torsion. We can reduce $x \pmod p$ for a prime $p$ of good reduction and it will have some order $n_p$ in the group $E(\mathbb F_p)$. Has there been any work on the asympotitcs of the average of $n_p$ for $p < X$ as $X \to \infty$?

More generally, suppose $x,y \in E(\mathbb Q)$ are two linearly independent sections and let them generate subgroups $G_x(p),G_y(p) \subset E(\mathbb F_p)$ for a prime of good reduction. Have the asymptotics of the average of $G_x(p)\cap G_y(p)$ been studied?

[This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285934/orders-of-reductions-of-rational-points-on-elliptic-curves) question seems tangentially related.

Comment: I guess you want to consider the average of $n_p$ over $p<X$ (the question title says "average" but the question body does not). One can give an upper bound of the form $cp  $ by some $c<1$ depending on $E$ by considering the various reasons that a small prime $\ell$ could divide the order of the index and noting they can all be detected by Chebotarev (either there is an $\ell$-torsion point and an $\ell$th root of $P$ or two independent $\ell$-torsion points) and then going to prime powers and composites. Presumably someone has conjectured this upper bound is sharp, this seems hard to prove.

Comment: Thanks, yes. I do want the average. That's along the lines of what me and my friend were thinking but we wanted to know if anyone had considered this problem before trying to think seriously about it.

Comment: There has been work for the reductions of a fixed subgroup of $E(\mathbb{Q})$, see Akbary, Ghioca, Murty V. Kumar, Reductions of points on elliptic curves, Math. Ann. 347 (2010), no. 2, 365–394. But for their result they need to assume the rank is $>18$. The lower bound is like $p/f(p)$ for any function $f$ tending to infinity arbitrarily slowly. For your second question I don't know.

Comment: @reuns See this paper of Kurlberg and Pomerance: https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.5209

Comment: Thank you, I think it deserves a discussion, how it works for $\sum_{p\le X}\text{order}(g\bmod p) $ for some fixed integer $g$ and how it fails for  $\sum_{p\le X}n_p $

Comment: @reuns As I understand it, the reason the Kurlberg-Pomerance paper works is that we have good control over the index of the subgroup generated by $g \pmod p$ (in both the $\mathbb G_m$ and elliptic curve case) and moreover in the $\mathbb G_m$ case, since the total size of the group is just $p-1$, we can translate the information about the index to information about the order of $g$. In the elliptic curve case, to do this translation we would like to have information about $d_p,e_p$ in the notation of the current answer which also explains why the answer IS relevant to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve.  There exist positive integers $d_p$ and $e_p$, with $d_p|e_p$, such that group $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/d_p\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/e_p\mathbb{Z}$.  Kowalski conjectured that there exists a constant $c_E>0$ such that $\sum_{p\leq x}d_p\sim c_E f_E(x)$, where $f_E(x)=x$ if $E$ has CM and $f_E(x) = \mathrm{Li}(x)$ otherwise.

Before Kowalski's paper, Duke showed that if $f$ is any function with $\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)=\infty$, then for almost all primes $p$, $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ contains a cyclic group of order $p/f(p)$ (where "almost all" is quantified in his paper).  He used GRH for certain Dedekind zeta functions to handle the non-CM case, but not the CM case.

Freiberg and Pollack unconditionally proved an $\asymp$ version of Kowalski's conjecture in the CM case.  We appear to be far off from such a result in the non-CM case.

Cojocaru has extensively studied the distribution of $p$ such that $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is cyclic, in which case $d_p=1$.  Again, progress towards GRH is usually key for the non-CM case, but not the CM case.

*Duke, William*, [**Almost all reductions modulo (p) of an elliptic curve have a large exponent.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.crma.2003.10.006), C. R., Math., Acad. Sci. Paris 337, No. 11, 689-692 (2003). [ZBL1048.11045](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1048.11045).

*Kowalski, E.*, Analytic problems for elliptic curves, J. Ramanujan Math. Soc. 21, No. 1, 19-114 (2006). [ZBL1144.11069](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1144.11069).

*Freiberg, Tristan; Pollack, Paul*, [**The average of the first invariant factor for reductions of CM elliptic curves mod (p)**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/imrn/rnv027), Int. Math. Res. Not. 2015, No. 21, 11333-11350 (2015). [ZBL1398.11088](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1398.11088).

*Cojocaru, Alina Carmen*, [**Primes, elliptic curves and cyclic groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/conm/740/14901), Bucur, Alina (ed.) et al., Analytic methods in arithmetic geometry. Arizona winter school 2016, the University of Arizona, Tucson, AZ, USA, March 12–16, 2016. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS); Montreal: Centre de Recherches Mathématiques (CRM). Contemp. Math. 740, 1-69 (2019). [ZBL1452.11069](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1452.11069).

Comment: This is all very interesting, but it answers a different question than the one asked.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich It is fairly related in that $e_p$ is an upper bound for the order of any element so lower bounds for the order of the reduction of an element imply lower bounds for $e_p$ / upper bounds for $d_p$. // In the third paragraph, one of the "CM"s should be "non-CM".

Comment: I think the $d_p$ in the second paragraph should be $e_p$? Thanks! This is very interesting.

Comment: @WillSawin The second CM should be non-CM.  Corrected.  Thanks

Comment: @Asvin I made the second paragraph a bit more precise.  This should address your comment.